# Crossroads отрабатывает по одному маршруту только один раз

Tags: node.js, роутинг

Пишу небольшое серверное приложение. Необходимо чтобы при отсутствии в папке с html файлами файла по запросу, проверить нет ли одноимённых функций.
Для роутинга использую crossroads.
Роутинг работает, но не совсем так как хотелось бы.
Есть несколько отслеживаемых адресов, запрос которых должен обрабатываться.
добавил правила через addRoute, добавил crossroads.parse(request.url);
Запрашиваю подходящий адрес
В функции обрабатывающей совпадение console.log срабатывает.
Запрашиваю другой подходящий под правило адрес, правило снова срабатывает и в консоль сыпется адрес.
Проблема возникает когда запрашиваю один и тот же адрес дважды. Правило во второй раз не отрабатывает.
В кратце код следующий:

```
var crossroads = require("crossroads");
var http = require("http");

crossroads.addRoute('/test/{param}',function(param){
    console.log(param);
});

http.createServer(function(request,response){
    crossroads.parse(request.url);
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.write('test');
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

При открытии http://myhost:8888/test/testString в консоль выводится testString, при обновлении страницы в консоль ничего не выводится. Что нужно дописать чтобы оба запроса возвращали в консоль один результат?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл костыль, который помог мне, для этого в объекте `crossroads` обнулил `_prevMatchedRequest` и `_prevRoutes`

```
crossroads._prevMatchedRequest = null;
crossroads._prevRoutes = [];
```

Но всё же хотелось бы узнать правильное решение.